# Unable to access subfolder web.config

Tags: asp.net

For other reading keeping the web.config in sub folder work on a fly but my case is not and its reading the root config. 
We have a basic web structure.

```
<Root>
  web.config
  sub-application A
  web.config -> (need to access)
```

Appreciate any help. TIA.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162980/how-to-retrieve-web-config-setting-in-web-application-subfolder

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/working-with-more-then-one-web-config-files-in-asp-net-application